# Is there an efficient algorithm to find all the maximum matching in any tree?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

A matching in a graph (G) is a set of mutually non-adjacent edges of (G).
A maximum matching is a matching maxima cardinallity.
A tree is an acyclic connected graph.

Is there an efficient algorithm to find all the maximum matching in any tree?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- How many maximum matchings there might be?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Well, it is the adjacency matrix is not singular, there is just one maximum matching, and it is perfect. In the general case, the product of all the non-zero eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix gives the number of maximum matching. So, the problem is not know haw many, instead, I wolud like to find all of them.

Comment: @DanielAlejandroJaume But if there are too many, then no efficient algorithm could list them all (normally you measure complexity with regard to input, not output).

Comment: I took away the efficient requirement... there is some algorithm that find all the maximum matching in a tree (and as simplex works well for in most of the cases)

Comment: @DanielAlejandroJaume Simplex works well in most cases for different reasons, it's exponential only for very special cases. On the other hand, in this problem I would guess that then number of matchings of a random tree on $n$ vertices is exponential in the number of leaves it has.

Comment: I think that is exponential in the number of edges if T is a tree, and then you add in each vertex at least 2 pendants. This kind of trees are the bad ones. Usually you have many "no singular" parts. I think that in the Drazin inverse of the adjacency matrix you get the edges that are in all the maximum matchings

Comment: @DanielAlejandroJaume If you want all the edges that belong to some maximum matching, that should be much easier.